# how to force Sphinx to show all the pages of project in sidebar?

Tags: python-sphinx

I am trying to create a sphinx documentation for my project - using the rtd_sphinx_theme.
the problem is that the sphinx's side bar is showing only the content of the specific html page

and look like - 
https://pasteboard.co/IfaVm32.png

and I want it to be like - 
https://sphinxcontrib-fulltoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html 
and contains links to other pages.

I tried to use sphinxcontrib-fulldoc, but then when I am trying to generate the html file I got an error that -

```
   Reason: TypeError("make_toctree() got an unexpected keyword argument 'titles_only'")
```

I tried to change the rst-theme configurations (html_options) but its not works.

I did a `make clean` and `make html` and it still not works :\
someone knows how can I get it to work?

Comment: Did you read the [configuration options in its documentation](https://sphinx-rtd-theme.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuring.html)?

Comment: Yes I tried them all, but it's not working :\

Comment: Did you do a `make clean` or delete the build directory between builds? Sphinx will rebuild only the source reST pages that change, and not when you make a change to the `conf.py`. Also please update your question with the options you tried but are "not working", and then we can offer suggestions to make them work.

Comment: yes I did `make clean` and then `make html`